# How can I exclude comments in the knit output in Rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, output, comments

I'm quite new to R and even newer to Rmarkdown so please forgive me if this is an idiotic question. I would like to exclude the comments I have put into my code blocks from the html output after knitting without excluding the actual working code. Here's an example of a block:

````
```{r, echo=TRUE}
#Read data, remove unnecessary columns, rename the necessary ones and convert to a tibble
data <- read_dta("assignment1.dta") %>%
  select(datestr, GDPC1) %>%
  rename(Date=datestr, GDP=GDPC1) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  as_tibble()
```
````

So here, I would like to exclude `#Read data, remove unnecessary columns, rename the necessary ones and convert to a tibble` from the html output and include the rest.
And would I have to specify at the start of each block or could I define it at the start of the doc here?

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

I hope I have described my issue well enough for you fine folk to understand!

I consulted ChatGPT who told me to just preface every block as such:

````
```{r, echo=TRUE, comment=""}
#Comment I don't want displayed
print("Hello, world!")
```
````

It still displayed the comment!

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729363/646761 on how to handle this with `tidy` option and formatR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your document isn't huge and you just want to preserve some comments, you can just do:

````
```{r, echo=-1, comment=""}
#Comment I don't want displayed
print("Hello, world!")
```
````

[image]

Or, if you have a span of comments:

````
```{r, echo=4:5, comment=""}
#Comment I don't want displayed
# I don't want this displayed either
# or this
print("Hello, world!")
print("Goodbye, world!")
```
````